# Как добавить css стили для тэга

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Как добавить к тэгу <area> рамку или фон?
Через style="border: 1px solid #FFF; background: red;" - не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут может помочь jQuery плагин [maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/)

Comment: Снова, Благодарю :) Друг, а не подскажешь, долго ли меня еще тут будут банить, или уже все на веки вечные денайд :(

Comment: Ааа, понял :) Спасибо!